# MariaDB : calculate distance between 2 points in km

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, relational-database

I try to get some approximate distance between 2 points in mariaDB.

I use that SQL:

```
SELECT st_distance(POINT(50.6333,3.0667),p) from p
```

It outputs results such as:

```
0
1.9128040446888426
8.103248262271125
```

It seems mariaDB does not handle SRID.
Is there a way to convert these values to km ? (looks like multiplying by 110 is quite correct)

My goal is to avoid handling maths such as sin, cos, atan and approximate result is ok for me.

Answer (score 7):

The result returned by st_distance are not kilometer but minutes.
For a circumference of the equator of d = 40.075km, the distance between two  minutes is d / 360 = **111,319** km.

While the distance between the latitudes is constant, the distance between the longitudes from the equator to the pole caps decreases constantly. According to your example the point from one location must be somewhere in France, where the distance between longitudes is around 70km.

Since you don't want to use the Haversine formula, you can also use the Pythagorean theorem to get a more accurate result:

```
# Distance between Eiffel tower and Lille

SELECT ST_DISTANCE(GeomFromText("Point(50.6333 3.0669)"), GeomFromText("Point(48.853. 2.348)")) * 111.38;
-> 213.84627307672486

select sqrt(pow((50.63333 - 48.853) * 111.38,2) + pow((3.0669 - 2.348) * 70, 2));
->204.57903071304386
```

Update: `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE()` which was [implemented](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/6769d1a0782f140dcd12c9ced6fda34ac0e41d85) around 3,5 years after answering this question will give you more accurate results.

Comment: You can use cos(latitude) to adjust the longitude delta, thereby making haversine _more_ accurate.

Comment: does this give accurate results? I compared the results of both formulas and the result is extremely different than `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE`

Answer (score -2):

ST_DISTANCE is designed for flat-earth advocates.

ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE is available in InnoDB as of 5.7.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

Comment: Rick, he is using MariaDB, not MySQL. See https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467